# How to transform a straight segment from a curved segment at Affinity Designer?

Tags: path, affinity-designer

[image: See the little segment at the center]

*The center is small curved wing want to turn in a straight line **without affecting adjacent nodes**.*

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you can explain a little further?

Comment: I want to transform this curve segment in a straight line, which is very easy to do in Corel Draw, without affecting the curvature of adjacent segments but with the corresponding modification of the nodes of the segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what you are trying to do. With the "Anchor Point Tool" selected, hold down the "command" key (not sure for Windows) and click on the anchor point in question, then while still holding the "command" key, click on the hand you want to delete. That should accomplish what you need.

EDIT:
Sorry the above was for Illustrator. For Affinity its somewhat similar, choose the “corner tool” and click on the anchor point, which should active the handles. Still having the “corner tool”, hold down the Command+Option keys and click on the handle you’d like to delete. That should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @VictorMorales  - You are welcome.  When you get a chance, just mark this as "answered". Thanks.   

BTW:  Although I use Photoshop and Illustrator primarily, I've been really enjoying Affinity Designer & Photo. I can see myself using more and more as updates are released. In my opinion, the best alternative to Adobe.